# Twig templates hierarchy

Tags: php, twig

Can I have template folders in some hierarchy way, like in a following analog:

```
View: Hey, can I render this template?
Twig: Sure bro, let me check in abc/directory...
Twig: Here you go!
View: Thanks bro!
```

Analog 2:

```
View: Hey, can I render this template?
Twig: Sure let me check in abc/directory...
Twig: Blasted balls! It doesn't exists, let me check in the bbc/directory instead.
Twig: Here you go!
View: Thanks bro!
```

Final analog:

```
View: Hey, can I have this template?
Twig: Sure let me check in abc/directory...
Twig: Blasted balls! It doesn't exists, let me check in the bbc/directory instead.
Twig: Exception!
View: Wait what?
```

As you can see, I'm looking to have templates in many folders, and I simply want them to be found in a certain way,  I couldn't find any in the Twig documentation about having multiple folders especially not in some hierarchy way.

Oh and by the way, the directory structure is as follows:

```
abc/
  bbc/
    templates/
  ddc/
    templates/
  ccc/
    templates/

adc
  templates/
```

The bbc, ddc, and ccc templates are "modules".

Any solutions?

Comment: Please include show us your code, your question cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: If you use Zend framework 2 and the ZFcTwig package, you can do this sort of thing using Zend's template stack. With just Twig, I think you'd have to find/write an extension.